# Can't redirect console output of a program

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, console, io-redirection

I have a program that I want to redirect it's output to another file.
I tried using the standard

```
foo.exe > out.txt
```

This doesn't work and the file is empty, but when I simply run it from cmd, I can see all the messages normally.

What I did notice, if i don't start the program correctly, and get its usage message it does work.

I checked the source (C++) and it seems that the prints (using printf) aren't from the same thread.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I might try: foo.exe 2>&1 > out.txt in case the app is writing to stderr. Or foo.exe 2> out.txt Ok. This is not linux? Then I can't help you.

Comment: I think it is better for you to post your code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem by adding

```
setbuf(stdout,NULL);
```

to the programs main.

I guess the stdout buffer wasn't flushing.

Answer (score 0):

The program may ouput with stderr or stdout, which default fd is 2 and 1.

just use "2>&1" , which is implement like 'dup2(1, 2)'.